# How to pack tensor of booleans into bits of int32 tensor?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying bit manipulation APIs in TensorFlow 1.15.

I've got a `Tensor` of `bool` (or of `int8` with 0 or 1 values), and I want to densely pack the `True` or `False` values into bits of `int32` `Tensor`.

For example (assuming target is `int8`), given `Tensor` of shape 16: `[0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,1,  0,0,0,1, 0,0,1,0]`, I want to get a `Tensor` of shape 2: `[0x01, 0x12]`

How can I do that efficiently?

Does TensorFlow 2.x provide better operations for this?

The original `Tensor` is a result of comparison operator. Is there a way to make comparison return bit-packed `Tensor` directly?

P.S. right now I am reshaping the original `Tensor` into a 32xN, then doing bit left shift by a constant 32x1 tensor: `[31..0]`, then sum along the first dimension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are working with **integers (1's and 0's)** in an array.

You could try this common approach.

```
import tensorflow as tf  # TensorFlow 2.1.0
import numpy as np


def convert_bits(storage, bit_array, bit_size):
  for n_bit in range(bit_size):
    storage.assign_add(tf.reverse(bit_array, axis = [-1])[n_bit]*(2**n_bit))

data = [0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0]
tf_data = tf.convert_to_tensor(data)

bit_size = 8 ## int8
np_array = np.array([])

for index in range(int(len(data)/bit_size)):
  temp_storage = tf.Variable(initial_value=0)
  convert_bits(temp_storage, tf_data[int(index*bit_size):int((index+1)*bit_size)], bit_size)
  np_array = np.append(np_array, temp_storage.numpy())
  print(np_array)

tf_array = tf.convert_to_tensor(np_array, dtype = tf.int32)

print(tf_array) # tf.Tensor([65 10], shape=(2,), dtype=int32)
```

You could modify and remove the `tf.reverse` depending on the **endianness** of the bits.
Also, as much as possible if you can use TensorFlow operations and data types in your code, you should use it.